# how to obtain the content of an input element with only html?

Tags: html, forms

I need to pass the content of the input to the url of the form with only html , is this possible ?

What i need to do is something like this :

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./busesFuncionando.html">Buses Funcionando</a></li>
        <form action="./busPorMatricula.html?matricula=????">

        <!-???? has to be substitute by the content of the input->

        Inserte la matricula del autobus a buscar :
            <input type="text" name="matricula"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar"/>
        </form>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: At minimum, you would probably have to use javascript.

Comment: Not to mention that your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `form` with `get` method, you don't have to set the `action` like this. Just set it to `<form action="./busPorMatricula.html">` and the browser will add the key and the value to the URL.

```html
<form action="https://www.google.co.il/">
  <input type="text" name="matricula" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**Note:** You can't see the result in the snippet because the security issues in StackOverflow.  You can see it in: http://output.jsbin.com/kelocu. After you submit the `form` you will go to `google.com` with the key and value in the URL.